# How to set a cron job to run a shell script?

Tags: cron, scripts

I had set a cron job:

```
20 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/lucky/myfile.sh
```

The main problem is that at the schedule time, there is an error:
"mail have sent to /var/spool/mail/lucky".

The contents of myfile.sh is:

```
mkdir jh
cd jh
```

Comment: This may help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: if myfile.sh set as executable?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This is not ok for a script which is set as a cron job:

```
mkdir jh
cd jh
```

You should give the full path where `jh` directory must to be created. Also, in this path you should have permission to create new files/directories.

For example, your script should look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /home/lucky/jh
cd /home/lucky/jh
```

Also `/usr/bin/sh` is not the right path for `sh`. The right path is `/bin/sh`. You can check this with `whereis sh` command. And even so, your cron job should look like:

```
20 * * * * /home/lucky/myfile.sh
```

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /home/lucky/myfile.sh
```

Comment: Awsome, saved my life :) Mine works fine like this.
0 7 * * * /bin/sh /root/Scripts/command.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: One point of contention: `which sh` and `whereis sh` both show `/usr/bin/sh`. That's because `/bin` is a symlink: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 17 12:07 /bin -> usr/bin`.  The most correct shebang AFAIK is `#!/usr/bin/env sh`.

Answer (score 8):

The path where this seems to be creating the folder at is `/` . This is because the `crontab` requires **full path to folder and files**  in all the files that it executes .

So the path in the myfile.sh should be

`mkdir <absolutePath>/jh`

`cd <absolutePath>/jh`

`20 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/lucky/myfile.sh` This line is correct though you should check the path to see if sh exists at /usr/bin/sh or not (use `which sh` to see the path where sh exists; mine was /bin/sh)

If you are in a hurry to start writing crontab this link has pretty good examples

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/