# How to add a bash script to a cron job?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have a script called `backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo zip -r /home/jazuly/backup.zip /var/lib/automysqlbackup/
cd /home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google/
php cp2google.php /home/jazuly/backup.zip
cd ~
rm -f /home/jazuly/backup.zip
```

I made it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x backup.sh
```

Then I tried to edit `cron`with `crontab -e`.

I add:

```
# m h dom mon dow command
0 0 * * * /home/jazuly/backup.sh
```

but when `cron` sends the backup.zip to my email, I download and open it, and the file is corrupt.

If I run the script manually with:

```
$ sudo chmod +x backup.sh 
$ ./backup.sh
```

I can open the zip file.

Comment: what message you get when fie corrupted ?

Comment: Are you sure the script works? You create `/home/jazuly/backup.zip` as root (`sudo`) and then try to delete it as a regular user (`rm -f /home/jazuly/backup.zip`), that doesn't make sense.

Comment: if i run manual without cron is work...
then, what should i do?

Comment: @JohnJoe unkown format or demaged and size is 0

Comment: Show `whereis -b zip`

Comment: zip: /usr/bin/zip

Comment: in your bash script try adding a zip file test `zip -T` before sending to php script. and again echo zip file size from php script. cron should report output. Debug your problem in this way. Figure out at what point it breaks.My guess is it's your php script or way its called from bash. Or not giving php binary a full path when called from cron. Use full paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps of how I fixed it:

1. Change Permission & Owner of `var/lib/automysqlbackup` to `777` & `jazuly.jazuly`.
2. Move all the folders & files from `backupscript/cp2google/` to `home/jazuly`.
3. Use `wait` for every statement.
4. My final code:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   zip -r backup.zip /var/lib/automysqlbackup/
   wait
   php cp2google.php backup.zip
   wait
   rm -f backup.zip
   ```

   And my `cron`:

   ```
   0 0 * * * /home/jazuly/backup.sh
   ```

   to backup every midnight/day.

   I don't think there is a need to write the full path if the `.sh` file is in the same path with what you want to execute.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use the full path in any cron executed script. So, don't do `cd ~`, give instead `cd /home/jazuly`

For further debugging, you can also redirect the output of the cron script to a file, with `/home/jazuly/backup.sh 1> /home/jazuly/log.txt 2> /home/jazuly/err.txt`

So the whole command:

```
# m h dom mon dow command
0 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/jazuly/backup.sh 1> /home/jazuly/log.txt 2> /home/jazuly/err.txt
```

Comment: i try it but crone not send me anything. im already delete that path change with rm -f /home/jazuly/backup.zip

Comment: Just updated the answer about the path - don't use relative paths, try `cd /home/jazuly` in your script

Comment: Also the php line, use the full path there too.

Comment: how to run php wit full path? i try `php /home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google/cp2google.php /home/jazuly/backup.zip` i got error

Comment: Still no luck? Does your `cp2google.php` give any output? You can capture the output with a line like `/home/jazuly/backup.sh 1> /home/jazuly/log.txt 2> /home/jazuly/err.txt`. 
This will send the output to log.txt and any stderr messages to err.txt. After you run the cron job, you should be able to see if any errors are printed.

Comment: here is the error i get https://gist.github.com/jazuly/8bf87fe34d74737bc340730c0089c534

Comment: Looks like there are some missing files there - `backupdatabaseterbaru-c771cd4f4fcf.p12` seems to be not found. I'm not familiar with this PHP script, where is the location of this file?

Comment: /home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google

Comment: Location of this file `/home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google/cp2google.php` is correct?

Comment: And try `chown jazuly.jazuly /home/jazuly/backup.zip` Why do you use `sudo zip`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if that's correct, I'm not familiar with the PHP program to be able to know how it works. This question has some more info on Cron errors: https://askubuntu.com/questions/350861 
Maybe it will help.

Comment: @zombic then? run `php /home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google/cp2google.php /home/jazuly/backup.zip` ?

Comment: Yes, then run `cp2google.php`.

Comment: @zombic still get same error

Comment: i run `sudo php /home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google/cp2google.php /home/jazuly/backup.zip` still get same error

Comment: The extensions are irrelevant. The point you make in the comments about using the absolute path is helpful, but your answer is just wrong: cron doesn't care about extensions at all.

Comment: Fair enough, I had thought that through testing previously I'd found the extension made cron go bad - but that may have been multiple factors during that testing and I'd erroneously blamed it on the extension. I'll edit the answer to avoid if being confusing for future readers.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use full paths

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/zip -r /home/jazuly/backup.zip /var/lib/automysqlbackup/
/usr/bin/php /home/jazuly/backupscript/cp2google/cp2google.php /home/jazuly/backup.zip
rm -f /home/jazuly/backup.zip
```

And add `/bin/bash` in cron

```
# m h dom mon dow command
0 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/jazuly/backup.sh
```

And check permissions for files `backup.zip`, `backupdatabaseterbaru-c771cd4f4fcf.p12`

Comment: from backupscript/sub directory all 777

Comment: Command `ls -l` will show you files owner.

Comment: root root, root root

Comment: Run `chown jazuly.jazuly file_name` or `chown -R jazuly.jazuly directory` for all files and directories with owner root.